# Olfactory equivalent of "palate"

Tags: single-word-requests

This morning a coworker walked into our office kitchen and claimed that he smelled an omelette. He was correct. I wanted to say something like, "You have a refined palate," but "palate" is the wrong word. It refers to the sense of taste, not the sense of smell. What would have been a suitable word to indicate that his sense of smell correctly detected my omelette?

Comment: You've got the nose of a bloodhound?

Comment: _Nose_ would be the most obvious choice… you might even get a bit punny and say that he has a nose for these things.

Comment: Eggcellent olfaction!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That’s actually the œnologically correct answer here.

Comment: @tchrist Œnologically? Eurgh, who would want eggs in their wine?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet [You might be surprised](http://www.thekitchn.com/did-you-know-the-tradition-and-use-of-eggs-in-winemaking-176695): albumin to the rescue again.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _Nose_ does smell right, doesn't it? Care to make it an answer?

Comment: @tchrist: It's not just *œnophiles* - as I understand it, US [*cerevisaphiles*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cerevisaphile) are keen on having [*egg in their beer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22egg+in+their+beer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)  too. Yuck!

Comment: Your odor decoder is in order.

Comment: @Janus I'd say that's not too obvious to be an 'answer'. But can it mean 'you have an acute sense of smell' as well as 'you have a discriminating sense of smell'? The corresponding 'eye' and 'ear'  are almost always used in the 'discriminating' sense.

Comment: Not only 'palate' but also 'refined' are "wrong". "Nose" (as already pointed out by VampDuc and Janus) is the right word ("*nose, n.* .... 2. The sense of smell: *a dog with a good nose.*"), but of course "you have a refined nose" is not going to wash, or at least not wash well. "You have a *good nose*" works well if you don't want to put too fine a ... point ... on it, but, more emphatically, "You have a sensitive|very sensitive nose."

Comment: @JEL - You've never seen him -- what do you know about the cleanliness of his nose?

Comment: @HotLicks, I allow myself the odd guess every now and again.

Comment: I like Edwin's adjective, *discriminating*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm satisfied that *nose* is the word for which I was searching. Thanks to @JanusBahsJacquet for providing it, though in comment form.